# Account class design using OOP paradigm

Tags: c++, object-oriented

I have a class Accounts with an array of account numbers and an array of balances I have a member function add_acc that adds an account. But before adding an account, I want to check if the account no. to be added, already exists or not. If it exists then an error message is displayed else the new account is added. In my following class design, the compiler is not able to check for the uniqueness of the account no. when more than 1 accounts are being added. Following is my approach.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
#define MAX 100
class Account
{
    long long int acc_no[MAX];
    long long int balance[MAX];
    int count;
    public :
        void CNT()
        {
            count=0;
        }
        void add_acc();

};
void Account::add_acc()
{
    if(count==0)
    {
        cout<<"Enter the account number"<<" : ";
        cin>>acc_no[count];
        cout<<"Enter the balance"<<" : ";
        cin>>balance[count];
    }
    else
    {
        long long int temp;
        cout<<"Enter the account no. to be added : ";
        cin>>temp;
        for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
        {
            if(temp==acc_no[i])
            {
                cout<<"Account no. already exists"<<"\n";
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
            
        }
        temp=acc_no[count];
        cout<<"Enter the balance : ";
        cin>>balance[count];

    }
    count++;
}
int main()
{
    Account A;
    A.CNT();
    char ch;
    while(ch)
    {
        A.add_acc();
        cout<<"Want to add another account? : ";
        cin>>ch;
        if(ch=='Y' || ch=='y')
            continue;
        else
            break;
     }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem with my output -:

In the first run I entered the account no. as 123, int the second run I enter the acc. no. as 345 and when in the third run again I entered the acc. no. as 345, the error message was not displayed.

Comment: @Ch3steR No. It does enter the else part in 2nd and 3rd run.

Comment: Yes, my bad did not see `count++` at the end.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. Code Review is not the site to ask for help in fixing or changing *what* your code does. Once the code does what you want, we would love to help you do the same thing in a cleaner way! Please see our [help center](/help/on-topic) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use [`unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) to maintain account number and balance.

You can use `unordered_map`(hash table) for checking if an `acc_num` already exists or not and the membership check in `unordered_map` is `O(1)`.

#### You can use [`int64_t`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Integers.html) for `long long int`

You can `int64_t` for `long long int`, `uint64_t` for `unsigned long long int` and since bank balance can't be less than `0` use `uint64_t` for `balance`.

#### `count` is unnecessary, use [`unordered_map::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find).

You can eliminate `count` when you are using `unordered_map` to check if `acc_num` exists use `unordered_map::find`.

#### Create alias using [`using`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias).

`using account_table` not only allows you to give a short name to a complex type, but it puts the type definition in a single place. Then if you change the underlying type you only need to change it in that one place.

#### Avoid using `using namespace std;`

Find more details here [why `using namespace std;` is considered bad praactice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

I added `Account::print_details`, it prints `acc_num --> balance`

#### Refactored code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<string>

class Account{
    using account_table = std::unordered_map<std::string, uint64_t>;
    private:
        account_table table;
    public:
        void add_acc();
        void print_details();
};

void Account::add_acc(){
    std::cout<<"Enter account number : ";
    std::string acc_num;
    std::cin>>acc_num;
    if (table.find(acc_num)==table.end()){
        uint64_t balance;
        std::cout<<"Enter balance : ";
        std::cin>>balance;
        table.insert({acc_num, balance});
    }
    else{
        std::cout<<"Account number already exists\n";
    }
}

void Account::print_details(){
    for(auto& d: table){
        std::cout<<d.first<<"-->"<<d.second<<std::endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    Account A;
    char ch{'Y'};
    
    while(ch){
        A.add_acc();
        std::cout<<"Want to add another account : ";
        std::cin>>ch;
        if (ch!='Y' && ch!='y'){
            break;
        }
    }
    A.print_details();
    return 0;
}
```

#### Example run

```
Enter account number : 1234
Enter balance : 50
Want to add another account : y
Enter account number : 1234
Account number already exists
Want to add another account : Y
Enter account number : 12345
Enter balance : 12
Want to add another account : n
12345-->12
1234-->50
```

---

You can use [`clang-format-9`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/clang-format-9/clang-format-9.1.en.html)(code formatting tool)

Example:

```
clang-format-9 -i -style=Google your_file.cpp
```

Comment: Thank you so much that was really helpful.

Comment: Please do not answer off-topic questions.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Sorry, new to the community. Can't delete the answer as it's accepted. Will keep in mind next time.